# Deleting 20000 files in applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, appdelegate

In my iPhone app, I am downloading files from server and storing them locally (user's document directory). The path of each file downloaded is subsequently updated in database.

If user tries to delete a file, first the file is deleted from local path using removeItemAtPath: (NSFileManager), then corresponding record is deleted from database.

Now I have one of the requirements according to which user can turn on a UISwitch to delete all data on app exit.

Now my question is -

> suppose user downloaded 20000 files, say small images, and user turned
>   on the switch to delete all data on app exit. Is it good to handle
>   this task in applicationWillTerminate? What is the best way to
>   accomplish this scenario?

Please suggest.

Comment: Read up on the app lifecycle. For most apps, the `applicationWillTerminate` is rarely called if at all.

Comment: Is that really a possibility? How small are the images exactly? This could easily translate to gigs of data in which case you're probably saving to many images.

Comment: @0x7fffff ... it was just an example, alternatively it could be a text file, my query is if we want to accomplish clearing all this data from table and physical memory, what is the best way to do so?

Comment: @rmaddy.. is it so? Even if user kills the application, then also will it not be called?

Comment: @Miraaj If a user kills an app then the app is killed without any notification of any kind.

Comment: @rmaddy.. then where shall I add the code, which needs to clear the data on app exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delete the files individually, delete and recreate the folder.

Your database could be handled differently by version tagging so that you can batch delete the items on the next run.

Comment: @wain.. thnx for your reply. Is it good to delete the folder in applicationWillTerminate?

Comment: No, `applicationWillTerminate` is basically never called.

Comment: You need to decide what level of going to the background ends the user session...

Comment: then in which delegate method shall I exactly delete the folder?

Comment: Maybe did resign active. Check all of the app life cycle callback to see what you think is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`applicationWillTerminate` will only be called if your app goes background (the only option by pressing Home button of the device) and "Application does not run in background" key is set in your app's info.plist file to "YES". Otherwise it won't ever be called.

If you are planning deploy app with similar functionality, you can use `applicationWillTerminate` for removing so many files. However, I would never recommend you that. Instead, my recommendation is to remove the files as soon as they are processed, if possible at all.

Another thing you must consider is not to save so many files in Document directory, however small those are. Document directory is backed up by iTunes and iCloud and if you store so many files there, you are gonna possibly violate Apple's [Data Storage Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) that would reject your app from App Store. It is always a good idea to store transient files in application's "tmp" directory and delete them when not required anymore.

Comment: hi Ayan.. thanks for your reply, suppose I plan to download the data into Cache folder, as stated in the document, what is the best way to clear this data on app exit?

Comment: It's always a good idea to use the approach as described by @Wain, that is, create a separate folder for storing the files in Cache folder and delete the folder as a whole when not required anymore. But I'm afraid that I still did not understand how you are planning your app to exit. If you want to use exit() call I would strongly recommend you to avoid that as that would be treated as a crash by the system and your `applicationWillTerminate` will never be called as well.

Comment: this is the scenario when user will terminate the app, by tapping home button and removing the app from background running apps list.

Comment: in that case.. will it call applicationWillTerminate? If yes then will it be a good place to delete the folder and deleting remaining files from database.

Comment: Even under that situation `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called. It is called only under the specific scenario, I described above. So it is never the best place for cleanup.